# Android Animation make sure the image not back?

Tags: android, animation

TranslateAnimation：
I want to move a Image, but do not want it to get back to its starting position. Can anyone help me? I am using another TranslateAnimation, but it's not working, so it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following method:-

```
anime.setFillAfter(true);
```

where anime is the object of [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) Class.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Android will animate your view then go back to where it started.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) and look at "fillAfter"